# Remove border of react-native-material-textfield

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-textinput

I'm using [**react-native-material-textfield**](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield) instead of react-native TextInput.

[image]

some problems:

**1)** How can I remove border right/left/top?

**2)** How can I change the color/font-size of the label( here is phone number)?

I tried (`inputContainerStyle`,`labelTextStyle`,`titleTextStyle`) to change but it dose not affect.

```
  <OutlinedTextField
    autoCorrect={false}
    enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
    label='Phone number'
    keyboardType='phone-pad'
    formatText={formatText}
    labelTextStyle={{color:'red'}}
    onSubmitEditing={onSubmit}
    ref={fieldRef}
  />
```

Comment: try this react-native-materialui-textfield

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't be using 'OutlinedTextField' for that - use 'TextField'.
2. Use the param 'baseColor' to change the color of the label when in default state, 'tintColor' to change color when in focused state, 'errorColor' to change color of error, and 'textColor' to change color of typing text.

   ```
   <TextField
       autoCorrect={false}
       enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
       label='Phone number'
       keyboardType='phone-pad'
       formatText={formatText}
       baseColor='red'
       tintColor='red'
       onSubmitEditing={onSubmit}
       ref={fieldRef}
     />
   ```